# Improving search speed on text column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'Products' where i have nearly 100,000 records. I have a field in the table called 'Product name' which is a varchar(255) field and contains name of products which could be around 5 - 15 word text. I perform search operation on this table with user input keywords... i do like...

```
 select * from products where product_name like '%USER_KEY%' limit 5;
```

when user search for single term (ex. iphone) it would look like this...

```
 select * from products where product_name like '%iphone%' limit 5;
```

This query runs in 0.89 seconds approx which is fine.

when user search for multiple terms (ex. iphone 5gb) it would look like this...

```
 select * from products where product_name like '%iphone%5gb%' limit 5;
```

This query takes about 4.02 seconds approx. The product name is a unique key indexed already. Can someone help me what can i do on this to get this search to result in lesser time ?

Anything to be done with db ? or any setting change in mysql helps improving query speed ?

Comment: I suggest if you want to find `why so slow` or `which one is faster` please do `Explain Analyze` in your query

Comment: With a `LIKE` with a wildcard at the beginning an index cannot be used. Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: From mysql v5.6 you can use fulltext search even on innodb tables.